# Slider (carousel) aligning with other elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, absolute

I've built a very basic single-page website which has a nagivation, a slider (carousel with 3 images), and a footer. My problem is that, while the slider fades the images in and out of each other properly, because it is positioned absolutely I cannot get the footer out from underneath it.

The slider overlaps everything, which I guess makes sense since it's absolute.

My question is if it is wiser to keep the slider positioned absolutely (it allows the jQuery to work it's magic fading in/out) and position my footer differently... OR if I should re-work the slider completely.

HTML:

```
<div id="carousel">
  <img class="slideshow" src="img/slide2.jpg">
  <img class="slideshow" src="img/slide3.jpg">
  <img class="slideshow" src="img/slide1.jpg">
</div>
```

Sass:

```
#carousel {
  img {
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: none;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
}

.slideshow {
  display: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Here's a sample of my page (as well as the JS working the slider) on JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/josectello/7n8c5bq8/

Thank you immensely in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's ok to keep absolute position, but make the footer's z-index higher than the imgs are, so it will be visible.

I hope i did understand your question correctly.

Comment: That helps! But then the footer would float in front of the slider and move around when the display size changes. Thank you, though!

Comment: Then give the footer an absolut position and margin as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy fix.

Add this:

```
// GLOBAL
body {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 0 200px;
}

html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Change your footer to absolute positioning and give it a height like so:

```
footer {
  @include module-style;
  position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This adds a sticky footer to the bottom of your page and avoids conflict with your slider.

See this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/WQMmmP/) for working solution.

Comment: I looked at the CodePen but it's not exactly working. The footer is floating in the middle of the slider. I also tried it in my own code, still getting the float.